# IBOutlets in UITableView Static Cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell, iboutlet, custom-cell

I created a `UITableView` (and related classes), with two sections:

- the first one is a static custom cell
- the second one is a prototype cell

To control the static cell, I implement a class, and in that class I added `IBOutlet` to an object (for example label) in the static cell. When I attempt to access that outlet in the class controlling the table view, I get this error:

> outlet doesn't exist

I made a [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6l2ewx246kxggb/ma%20ceh%20cavolo.mov?dl=0), for explain better my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short version**

`UITableView` cannot be at the same time a *Static Cells* and a *Dynamic Prototypes* content. You need to pick one or the other.

Because you need *Dynamic Prototypes*, use *Dynamic Prototypes*.

---

**Long version**

Steps to create *Dynamic Prototypes*:

1. Select your Table View in **IB** > Show Attributes Inspector > Table View > Content > Dynamic Prototypes
2. From the section  **IB** > Show the Object Library, drag as many **Table View Cell** onto  your table view as you have cell types.
3. If you have some cells that never change at run time, you can very well create 1 instance of each right there in **IB** ; they will behave like *Static Cells*
4. For the custom cells<sup>(†)</sup>, the recommended practice is to create subclasses of `UITableViewCell`, and apply that custom class to the relevant cell or cells (**IB** > Show the Identity Inspector), and pick your **Custom Class** from the list. This of course implies you have created such sub-classes.
5. Do not forget to assign a unique identifier to each cell prototype, so that you can retrieve these at runtime using `dequeueReusableCellUsingIdentifier;`

With this setup, you can select your Table View Cell, **IB** > Show Assistant Editor, and control-drag references in your custom class. You may need to tell the Assistant Editor which file to pick.

---

<sup>(†)</sup> There are plenty of other ways to do this ; all outside of the scope of this response.